# Android fragments looks overhead

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

MainActivity has 2 buttons and when I click the buttons I want 2 fragments to appear in the same page.But when I click on itsMeContact button, it comes up, but when I click on the PhoneContact button, I overwrite the other one.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button itsMeContact,phoneContact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    itsMeContact= (Button) findViewById(R.id.its_me_contact);
    phoneContact= (Button) findViewById(R.id.phone_contact);

    itsMeContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            UserFragment userFragment = new UserFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, userFragment, "userFragment");

            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    phoneContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragmentB, "fragg");

            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

}

}
```

UserFragment.java

```
 public class UserFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView ;
UserAdapter userAdapter ;
ArrayList<Person> arrayList ;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
Button itsMeContact,phoneContact;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user,container,false);


    recyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    itsMeContact= view.findViewById(R.id.its_me_contact);


    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    arrayList=new ArrayList<Person>();

    initial();

    return view;
}

private void initial() {
    Factory.getInstance().user().enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
            // textView.setText(response.body().get(0).name);
            userAdapter= new UserAdapter(response.body(), getActivity());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

FragmentB.java

```
 public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
TextView textView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_b,container,false);
    textView=view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("naber");

    return  view;
}
```

}

Your advice important for me !

Thank you very much

My app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Fln.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each Fragment transaction you did use the same framelayout : "R.id.frame_layout".

So this is normal if "it looks overhead". If you want 2 fragments displayed in a same layout, you should use 2 differents framelayout.